# Is a function pointer really a pointer? Or it's an object?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have this doubt because at first I think a function pointer is just plain pointer as it literally reads. But then I found some clues that indicates it doesn't look like a plain pointer but it's more likey to be an object.

From *C++ Primer 5th* (emphasis mine):

> When we define a lambda, the compiler generates a new (unnamed) class
> type that corresponds to that lambda. We’ll see how these classes are
> generated in § 14.8.1 (p. 572). For now, what’s useful to understand
> is that when we pass a lambda to a function, we are defining both a
> new type and an object of that type: The argument is an unnamed object
> of this compiler-generated class type. **Similarly, when we use `auto` to
> define a variable initialized by a lambda, we are defining an object
> of the type generated from that lambda.**

It's indicating that `auto` defines an **object** actually. (It's not saying that it's defining a pointer to an object)

And

```
auto z = [](int i) -> int { return i + 3; };
int(*z2)(int) = [](int i) -> int { return i + 3; };
```

compiles, so I would think `z`'s type is `int(*z2)(int)`, a function pointer.

So my deduction based on these is:

`auto` defines an **object** and `z`'s type is `int(*z2)(int)`, a function pointer, so a function pointer is actually a object type, not a plain pointer.

---

Another clue I found is:

consider this code snippet that I write to compare lambda to objects with `operator()`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int(*f1()) (int) {
    return [](int i) -> int {
        return i + 3;
    };
}

struct Foo {
    int operator()(int i) const {
        return i + 3;
    }
};

Foo f2() {
    return Foo();
}

Foo* f3() {
    return new Foo();
}

int main() {

    int(*q)(int) = f1();
    cout << q(1) << endl;
    
    Foo m = f2();
    cout << m(1) << endl;

    Foo* m2 = f3();
    cout << (*m2)(1) << endl;
    delete m2;

    return 0;
}
```

If `q`, the function pointer is indeed a pointer, then it should act like `m2`, a pointer to `Foo`, and needs `delete`. And return a lambda is like returning `new Foo()` (works like function `f3`), or there is no way for the lambda to outlive the calling function.

But the fact is `q` doesn't need a `delete`.

So now I would think that `q` is actually an object, then everything makes sense. It works like `m` and returning a lambda is like returning `Foo()` (works like function `f2`).

---

So, is my guess correct?

Comment: But a plain pointer is also an object.

Comment: *"Is a function pointer really a pointer? Or it's an object?"* - pointers *are* objects. They simply refer to other things as part of their semantics.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Hmmm. How should I rephrase the question? I want to express that a function pointer doesn't look like a primitive type like `int*`, but something more like a `class`.

Comment: Function pointers are primitive types.

Comment: @john Then why doesn't it need a `delete q` for `q`? But need a `delete` for `m2`? How does the lambda returning from `f1` outlives the calling function?

Comment: @Rick, `using F = int(*)(int); F* q = new F{f1()}; std::cout << (*q)(1); delete q;`.

Comment: @Rick `q` does not need deleteing because it has not been allocated.

Comment: You probably need to read up on what an "object" is in C++ because it is not what you think it is.    In the C++ standard (slightly over-simplistically), everything that can occupy memory and has state is an object (including a set of objects).   By the definition in the standard, all pointers are objects, all function pointers are objects, all  variables of type `int` are objects, AND all instances of `struct` or `class` types are objects.  Function pointers are different from other pointers since they can be used to indirectly call a function, whereas other pointers (e.g. an `int *`) cannot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the text you quoted, a lambda is equivalent to a `struct` with `operator()` defined. Your second program is very similar to:

```
int the_function(int i) { return i + 3; }

struct foo
{
    int operator()(int i) { return the_function(i); }

    using Ftype = int(int);
    operator Ftype *() { return the_function; }
};

auto f1() -> int(*)(int) { return foo(); }
auto f2() -> foo         { return foo(); }
auto f3() -> foo*        { return new foo; }

int main()
{
    int (*q)(int) = f1();
    q();
    foo m = f2();
    m();
    foo* m2 = f3();
    delete m2;
}
```

The conversion to free function pointer only exists if the lambda didn't capture anything, obviously this would be impossible if `foo` had a member variable that `the_function` would need to access.

The call `q();` is fine since `the_function` exists for the lifetime of the program, it does not matter if any lambda object exists or not.

Comment: Why doesn't it need a `delete q` for `q`? But need a `delete` for `m2`? How does the lambda returning from `f1` outlives the calling function?

Comment: @Rick `delete` should be matched with `new`. There is no `new` expression in `f1`. Also, functions don't have lifetimes, they exist for the whole duration of the program

Comment: Ok. And a lambda is an object of an uname type. How does it(an object) outlive the calling function without `new`?

Comment: @rick The object doesn't outlive the calling function. In `f1` you point to a function (not to a lambda object), and in `f2` you return by value (which copies the value)

Comment: Then why can I use `q(1)` after returning from `f1`, if the lambda object has already been destroyed by then...? Sorry I am confused.

Comment: @Rick The function doesn't require an object to exist in order to call it

Comment: **The function doesn't require an object to exist in order to call it**, I think that's what I want. Could you explain a little bit more about this? Because what I think it is: a function pointer points to a function, then the function object need to exist.. Just like an ordinary object does!

Comment: I still don't get it. So you are saying that creating a lambda is like creating a (global) function in runtime, while creating an object with `operator()` is not.

Comment: Ah I see. I read your program carefully now. So by defining a lambda in the program, is it creating a function at compile time? If that's true then it all makes sense.

Comment: I just thought about those lambdas creating with variables captured. Are these lambdas also creating related functions at complie time? I don't guess so because they are not allowed to be returned. I guess those lambdas are just getting expanded like inline functions do.

Comment: @Rick it works the same way but there is only the member function, not the free function. Which you cannot convert to a free function pointer (because member functions need the implicit `this` argument, pointing to an instance of a lambda)

Comment: Ah I see. That's why it needs `std::function<>` to wrap in `C++11` and use `auto` to deduce type in `C++14`. And in that case, the lambda is returning an instance, not a pointer to a free function.  Thank you so much for telling me that. It clears some of my doubts :P

Answer (score 0):

A C style function pointer is just like any other pointer except that one can run the code it points to (and pointer arithmatic does not work). A lambda can only be assigned to a function pointer if is does not contain any capture because as you mention. The and only then may it decay to a function pointer. Capture, however, creates an object that contains data as well as code. This will made it incompatible with C style function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate:

- A function pointer like `void (*foo)(int, double);` is really just a single address under the hood, pointing to the first byte of executable code. (At least on X86, other platforms may implement them in a different way.)
- **A lambda is not a function pointer**. It is an object with an unutterable type that can be passed around via template parameters and `auto` variables, only.

It is possible to implicitly convert some lambdas (those without captures) to a function pointer, allowing you to pass them to a function that expects a function pointer. However, this is a true conversion, the resulting pointer is not the same thing as the lambda that you put in. This goes so far that you cannot undo the conversion at all.